# Error en toString() de Java

Tags: java, string, poo, override

Estoy haciendo un método toString que me devuelva el siguiente formato de la clase Jugador y sus atributos:

```
JUGADOR:nombre;apellidos;dni;email;telefono;nacimiento;dorsal;goles
```

Y este es mi código, cual no entiendo por qué da fallo...

```
@Override
    public String toCSV() {
       return String.format("JUGADOR" + ":" + this.nombre + ";" + this.apellidos + ";" + this.dni + ";" + this.email
                + ";" + this.telefono + ";" + this.nacimiento + ";" + this.dorsal + ";" + this.goles);
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tampoco entiendo por qué me están pidiendo un constructor relacionado con el toCSV:

"Constructor con un sólo parámetro String que se llamará sCadenaCSV, que
debe de estar en el formato mostrado por el método toString definido más
adelante."

¿Por qué tengo que hacer un constructor?

Comment: si le pones el mouse encima te dice. lo más probable es que lo trates de acceder como método estático

Comment: No es estático y si te fijas en la captura de pantalla, me dice el error: 

The method toCSV() of type Jugador must override or implement a supertype methodJava(67109498)

Comment: Vamos por partes dijo "Jack", con tan poco código, solo puedo jugar a las adivinanzas, adivino que tu clase **Jugador** no hereda de una clase que tenga el método **toCSV()**, por lo que la anotación **@Override**, esta de más (esa es la queja del IDE), por otro lado, el **return** tiene un **String.format** totalmente innecesario, puedes devolver así: **"JUGADOR" + ": " + nombre + "; " + apellidos"** etc (agregando un espacio para separar las palabras), y estando en la clase **Jugador**, los **this** están de más (aunque no hacen daño).

Comment: Buenas, sube la captura de la clase no solo del constructor y el toString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es quitar la palabra `@Override`.

> Un método anotado con @Override debe anular un método de una
> superclase. Si no lo hace, se producirá un error en tiempo de
> compilación. Se utiliza para asegurar que un método de superclase esté
> anulado y no simplemente sobrecargado.

De acuerdo a esta definición y a tu error, tu método no puede anular el método de una superclase. ¿Por qué no puede? Porque la clase `Jugador` no esta heredando de ninguna otra clase. Bueno eso es lo que parece porqué no estas compartiendo donde se declara la clase `Jugador`, solo compartes un constructor.

Answer (score 0):

El método que debes sobreescribir en tu objeto es `toString()`

```
   @Override public String toString()
       return String.format("JUGADOR" + ":" + this.nombre + ";" + this.apellidos + ";" + this.dni + ";" + this.email
                + ";" + this.telefono + ";" + this.nacimiento + ";" + this.dorsal + ";" + this.goles);
    }
```

de esta forma imprimirías la información de tu objeto (suponiendo que `miObjeto` es la instancia):

```
System.out.println(miObjeto.toString());
```

Comment: Incluso haciendo un System.out.println(miObjeto) ya saldría bien, sin tener que invocar al método toString()